# What is the most optimal approach for training Inception v3 on a multi-label dataset like CIFAR-100?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to train Inception v3 on [CIFAR-100 dataset](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html), where each image belongs to a class and a superclass as indicated by its "fine" label and "coarse" labels. My goal is to get the model to infer the image class and with greater accuracy its superclass. For example, predict with 95% certainty that a photo of an apple contains "fruit and vegetables" and with 80% certainty that it contains "apples".

What would be the most optimal approach assuming I already have generated a TFRecords file with the both labels included:

```
features = {
'image/encoded': bytes_feature(image_data),
'image/format': bytes_feature(image_format),
'image/class/fine_label': int64_feature(fine_class_id),
'image/class/coarse_label': int64_feature(coarse_class_id),
'image/height': int64_feature(height),
'image/width': int64_feature(width),
}
```